# Trying to change game move when clicked on a button but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm building a board game in react.js and now I'm trying to add a feature which allows the user to flick through the game. I thought I nailed it but it doesn't work. I checked whether my objects are immutable(they should be), I also checked if the function that is to return the game step is called, and there's no problem at all neither. I don't know why it does not work. How can I solve it?

Here's the constructor function with the game data:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // The Game Data Comes Here
            history: [{
                squares: [
                    Array(8).fill(null),
                    Array(8).fill(null),
                    Array(8).fill(null),
                    [null,null,null,'black','white',null,null,null],
                    [null,null,null,'white','black',null,null,null],
                    Array(8).fill(null),
                    Array(8).fill(null),
                    Array(8).fill(null)
                ]
            }],
            stepNumber: 0,
            blackIsNext: true,
            winner: null
        }
    }
```

Here's where I render:

```
render() {
        // datas that will be rendered regularly come here
        const history = this.state.history
        const current = history[this.state.stepNumber]
        const moves = history.map((_, move) => {
            const desc = move ? 'Go to move #' + move : 'Go to game start';
            return (
              <li key={move}>
                <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
              </li>
            );
        });

        // Return the game scene here
        return (
            <div className="master-container">
                <GameBoard squares={current.squares} onClick={(row,col) => {
                    if (!this.state.winner) {
                        const elems = this.checkElementsAround(this.checkEmptySpaces())
                        for (let el=0;el<elems.length;el++) {
                            const turning = this.checkTurningStones(elems[el].directions, this.state.blackIsNext)
                            if (turning.length !== 0) {
                                turning.unshift([row,col])
                                if (row === elems[el].coordinates[0] && col === elems[el].coordinates[1]) {
                                    this.handleMove(turning)
                                    this.setWinnerAndTurn()
                                    // Debug
                                    //console.log(history.length)
                                    console.log(moves)
                                    break
                                }
                            }                        
                        }
                    }
                }}/>
                <div>{(!this.state.winner) ? "Player Turn: " + `${(this.state.blackIsNext) ? 'Black' : 'White'}` : 'WINNER: ' + this.state.winner}</div>
                <div>{(this.state.winner) ? moves : null}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

There are some functions that I won't put, because what they're doing is almost irrelevant, they don't change the data. And also I won't put the setWinnerAndTurn function neither, since it only  defines the game winner if the game is over or it switches player turns, but the issue here must be with the way I handle the `history` data.

Function that handles moves and the one that does jump to another step of the game

```
handleMove(cords) {
        // You'll return if the game is already over or the value of the square is NOT null
        if (this.state.winner) {
            return
        }
        // Handle the recently made move here
        const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
        const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
        const squares = current.squares.slice()

        // You'll handle the click here
        for (var i=0;i<cords.length;i++) {
            squares[cords[i][0]][cords[i][1]] = (this.state.blackIsNext) ? "black" : "white"
        }


        this.setState({
            history: history.concat([{squares: squares}]),
            stepNumber: history.length,
        });
}

jumpTo(step) {
        this.setState({
          stepNumber: step,
          blackIsNext: (step % 2) === 0,
        });
    }
```

If you think there's something missing to solve the problem, please do let me know.

Comment: At first glance I think your problem is [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) which is a mutating operation. Edit: and also a mutation here: `squares[cords[i][0]][cords[i][1]] = `

Comment: I think I found the problem. By debugging, I realized that all the elements inside the history array are updated

Comment: Yes, but that won't be stored, just temporarily there.

Comment: Well, elements of squares can be mutated, since they're going to be passed as the new squares value

Comment: But still I will take a look at it, thanks for your advice

Comment: It's a mutation because `squares` is a shallow copy of an array from state.  The `squares` array is new but the arrays inside of `squares` are the same.  You are dealing with deeply nested data so it's really hard to [update without mutation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns).  I would honestly recommend a helper like [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

Comment: Also I don't think you want the brackets here `history.concat([{squares: squares}])`?  Should be `history.concat({squares})`.

Comment: Squares do mutate, that's what I noticed to you both are right. By the way, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operation in this line is a mutation of your component's state.

```
squares[cords[i][0]][cords[i][1]] = (this.state.blackIsNext) ? "black" : "white"
```

It's a mutation because `squares` is a shallow copy of an array from `this.state`. The `squares` array is new but the arrays inside of squares are the same.

You are dealing with deeply nested data so it's really hard to [update without mutation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns). I would honestly recommend a helper like [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) which allows you to do assignment operations on a draft state.

Without a helper you have to map through `squares` and modify the inner arrays (at least the ones with changed elements).  I *think* this is correct, but double check that I don't have rows and columns mixed up.

```
// Handle the recently made move here
const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];

// Apply changes to every square
const color = this.state.blackIsNext ? "black" : "white";
const nextSquares = current.squares.map((row, y) =>
  row.map((square, x) =>
    // find if this [x,y] is in the cords array and replace it if it is
    cords.some((cord) => cord[0] === x && cord[1] === y) ? color : square
  )
);

// Update the state
this.setState({
  history: history.concat({ squares: nextSquares }),
  stepNumber: history.length
});
```

Comment: It helped, but I still have a problem, now. history array comes from behind. After I push the element to the history array by the help of `concat`, it displays the first one instead of the first two. And it keeps on going like that.